# How to adjust Images to adhere to Specify image dimensions error in Google Chrome Audit with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, dimensions

I am modifying my HTML to provide better website performance. I am using bootstrap as my css boilerplate. One of the errors I receive from the Google Chrome Audit Console is:

> "Specify image dimensions - A width and height should be specified for
>   all images in order to speed up page display. The following image(s)
>   are missing a width and/or height: With a list of all the images that
>   do not have a specific height or width assigned."

The problem I have is that I use bootstrap and most of the images are use the img-responsive class. So how can I adhere to this rule when I want the images to be responsive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The height and width defined in the image tag doesn't make any difference to its responsiveness. **The height and width attributes give user agents an idea of the size of an image or object so that they may reserve space for it and continue rendering the document while waiting for the image data.** http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#visual

Answer (score 1):

I was having this on my head for a long time, so my optional solution is to manage breakpoints with JavaScript and inject the width and height. The problem is that you should make this with a very photo on the site, but, like I said, it is temporal.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 700){
   $(".image").attr('width', 232).attr('height', 350);
}
```

This help me to avoid the chrome warning and the load of the page.

NOTE: you have to load this before images, of course.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will give it a go as i've got plenty of images on my website.